# Extract data from .bag without messages built

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am looking for a way to extract data from .bag files without messages built. Is this possible?, I have some .bag files but I don't have the messages built in my system so I can't see what types they have and I can't extract data from this bags files following the tutorials steps.
However, when I run "rosrun rqt_bag rqt_bag" and open my bag file, I can see the data published (data value).

So I think that this is possible but I can't find out information about how to do this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199436/extract-data-from-.bag-without-messages-built/) by [cpiury](https://answers.ros.org/users/21107/cpiury/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message definitions that the bag file was recorded with are stored in the bag file.

You can use the `rosbag` command-line tool to list the topics and their message types from a bag file: `rosbag info my_data.bag`

You can also use the -b option to rostopic echo to print messages from a single topic in a bag file.

The python API to rosbag dynamically constructs messages based on the message definitions that are stored in the bag file, so you can use the python API to read and introspect all of the messages in a bag file.

Since C++ is statically typed, you have to have headers from your message definitions in order to compile a program which reads those messages - this means that you can't use the C++ API unless you have the message definitions.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0